# Проверка на несовпадение пароля или существование логина

Tags: html, css, python, django, jinja2

Хотелось бы, чтобы при вводе и повторном вводе пароля при регистрации проводилась проверка на их совпадение, и при несовпадении выдавало ошибку.
Изначально попробовал через сравнение `if password1 == password2`, но не получилось. Нужно, чтобы программа выводила сообщения:

1. Если логин уже зарегистрирован, то "такой логин уже занят"
2. Если пароли совпадают, то "пароли совпадают"

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if password1 == password2:
            if user_form.is_valid():
                # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
                new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                # Set the chosen password
                new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                # Save the User object
                new_user.save()
                return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:
            return render(request,'registration/WrongPassword.html')
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns =[
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path(r'login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html', success_url='news/'), name='login'),
    path(r'logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/profile/', views.indexs, name='indexs'),
]
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password1'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

registred.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  <h1>регистрация</h1> <br>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h3>Логин</h3> <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}"> <br>
  <h3>Почта</h3> <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}"> <br>
  <h3>Пароль</h3> <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}"> <br>
  <h3>Повторите пароль</h3> <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Войти">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```